# Iterating through an rvalue container

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, rvalue, boost-foreach

Is the following code causing undefined behavior?

```
std::map<int, vector<int>> foo()
{
return ...
}

BOOST_FOREACH(const int& i, foo()[42])
{
std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

If undefined, What is the good way to fix it? What if I use c++11 range-for loop instead of BOOST_FOREACH?

Comment: Why do you think there can be UB here?

Comment: I am seeing a memory corruption in similar code. But not sure if it is because of such usage.

Comment: Check out the [sourcecode](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/foreach.hpp). There seems to be some macro magic to detect if argument is rvalue and in that case, it copies the argument.

Comment: @user2079303: unfortunately, `std::map<...>::operator[]` returns a l-value reference (into a temporary object); not an r-value; thus the lifetime of the `map` temporary is not extended properly and we end up with a reference into the nether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, most probably undefined behavior.

The problem is that you have two levels here:

1. `std::map<...>` is an r-value, its lifetime will be expanded until the end of the full-expression
2. `std::vector<int>&` is an l-value reference (into an object), its lifetime is that of the object.

The problem arises because the code (roughly) expands to something like:

```
// from
for (<init>: <expr>) {
    <body>
}

// to
auto&& __container = <expr>;
for (auto __it = begin(container), __e = end(container); __it != __e; ++__it)
{
    <init> = *__it;
    <body>
}
```

The issue here is in the initialization of `__container`:

```
auto&& __container = foo()[42];
```

If it where just `foo()`, this would work, because the lifetime of `std::map<...>` would be extended to match that of `__container`, however in this case we get:

```
// non-standard gcc extension, very handy to model temporaries:
std::vector<int>& __container = { std::map<...> m = foo(); m[42] };
```

And thus `__container` ends up pointing into the nether.

Comment: Can you state with certainty that it is always undefined?

Comment: @balki: no, though I harbor few doubts. As far as I know, the range-for could be improved to handle this -- because the transformation presented in the Standard is non-normative and the compiler knows about all temporaries in presence. However I just see now way how Boost could handle this because the type system is insufficiently expressive to reflect the issue.

Comment: The transformation in 6.5.4/1 is normative, except for the names of the exposition-only variables `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end`. I don't believe a compiler could remove the undefined behavior here without necessarily violating the rules for the lifetime of temporaries - so it would be at best a non-conforming extension. It would seem to require a core language change to extend the lifetime of any temporaries created in `<expr>` to the entire loop body.

Comment: @Casey: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Yes, obviously extending the lifetime of any temporary would have to be normed or there would be portability issues.

Answer (score 2):

The return value exists until the end of the full expression
which creates it.  So it all depends on how `BOOST_FOREACH`
expands; if it creates a scope outside of the for loop, and
copies the return value to a variable in it (or uses it to
initialize a reference), then you're safe.  If it doesn't,
you're not.

The C++11 range-for loop basically has the semantics of binding
to a reference in a scope outside of a classic for-loop, so it
should be safe.

EDIT:

This would apply if you were capturing the return value of
`foo`.  As Benjamin Lindley points out, you aren't.  You're
capturing the return value of `operator[]` on a map.  And this
is *not* a temporary; it is a reference.  So no extension of
lifetime occurs, neither in `BOOST_FOREACH` nor in range-for.
Which means that the map itself will be destructed at the end of
the full expression which contains the function call, and that
undefined behavior occurs.  (Boost could, I suppose, make a deep
copy of the map, so you'd be safe.  But somehow, I doubt that it
does.)

END OF EDIT:

Never the less, I would question the wisdom of returning an
`std::map` when all you want is a single entry in it.  If the
map actually exists outside the function (is not on the heap),
then I'd return a reference to it.  Otherwise, I'd find some
what that it did.

Comment: Are you certain it should work in range-for loops? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/165d826532b7eb84

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The standard certainly seems to say so.  In
§6.5.4, it gives the equivalent code of a range-based for, and
there, the initialization expression is bound to a reference, so
it's lifetime should be extended to match that of the reference.
(Of course, given that this is a new feature, I wouldn't trust
any compiler to have gotten it 100% right.)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley But as you point out in a comment to another answer, which I've just read, he's not initializing the reference with the return value of the function; he's initializing it with the return value of `[]` on the map.  And since this returns a reference (rather than a temporary), there is no extension of lifetime.  Well spotted; I'd missed that.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/foreach.html

> Iterate over an expression that returns a sequence by value (i.e. an rvalue):

```
extern std::vector<float> get_vector_float();
BOOST_FOREACH( float f, get_vector_float() )
{
    // Note: get_vector_float() will be called exactly once
}
```

So it is well defined and works.

As well, it is well defined in C++11 (and works):

```
for (const int& i : get_vector()) // get_vector() computed only once
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The problem here is that `foo()[42]` returns a **reference** from a temporary (via a method).

```
auto& v = foo()[42];
```

life of `foo()` temporary is not extended...

You may solve that by extending `foo` temporary lifetime

```
auto&& m = foo();

for (const int& i : m[42]) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What he's doing is not so simple. `operator[]` on a map doesn't return by value, it returns a reference.