# Member function returning l-value reference from an r-value object

Tags: c++, c++11

std::map's [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) function returns an lvalue reference even though the map itself is an rvalue.

```
T& operator[]( const Key& key );
```

This causes undefined behavior usages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21680125/463758). Why are there no overloads for lvalue and rvalues like below? Does any other map implementation use such overloads?

```
T& operator[]( const Key& key ) &;
T operator[]( const Key& key ) &&;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

bool silly_test( int& lhs, int& rhs ) { return lhs == rhs; }
std::map<int, int> silly_map() {
  std::map<int, int> retval;
  retval[0] = 0;
  return retval;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << silly_test( silly_map()[0], silly_map()[0] ) << "\n";
}
```

the above code is legal C++03, and illegal if we made the change you proposed.

While the above code is silly, it is an example of the fact that your change *can* break things.

rvalue references to `this` where added late in C++11 standardization.  Making potentially breaking changes to standard containers late in the cycle would probably be a bad idea.

I would encourage you to make a proposal to make the above change into the standard for C++1z.  It may not be practical, but at first glance it looks like a decent idea, as the kind of code it breaks is pretty strange (and possibly *should* be broken).